# React Native App Stuck on Resolve dependencies of :app:debugRuntimeClasspath react-native run-android

Tags: react-native

I am building an app and working on it from the last two months. Everything was working fine but from yesterday suddenly it stopped working. I havn't changed a single line of code but got the issue of stucking the react native app. I also tried to build the app on android studio but the app got stuck on import gradle project phase.
I tried every way , deleted node modules , reset cache , even i created a new project and got the issue there as well.

here is the status from terminal when i hit react-native run-android to start the app. the app got stuck here whenever i entered command 'react-native run-android'

```
    PS H:\PracticeMaterial\REactNativeOld\taizen\taizen> npm run android

> taizen@0.0.1 android H:\PracticeMaterial\REactNativeOld\taizen\taizen
> react-native run-android

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1143 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
<=============> 100% CONFIGURING [6m 59s]
> Resolve dependencies of :app:debugRuntimeClasspath
```

here is my package.json file

```
 {
  "name": "taizen",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "0.1.0-rc.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "firebase": "^7.17.2",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.13",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2",
    "react-native-agora": "^2.9.1-alpha.7",
    "react-native-css-gradient": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^5.6.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.7",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.8.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.11.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.11.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "25.5.1",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "25.5.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

here is the android buil.gradle file

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1')
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Please someone help , i have been stuck in this from last two days and i got deadlines :(

Comment: Have u tried restarting you pc

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you didn't change your code you probably know this is somewhow related to dependencies and dependency updates (*probably*!)

I found a few github issues which seemed somewhat related to your issue, but this Reddit thread is the most promising: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/dpju4a/reactnative_runandroid_keeps_failing_what_am_i/

They say to install `jetify`:

```
npm install —save jetifier

npx jetify
```

Or to close Android Studio and delete the following folders:

- C:\Users\USER_NAME.gradle\caches
- C:\Users\USER_NAME.android\build-cache
- C:\Users\USER_NAME.android\cache